# Possible to filter out older personal Lotus Notes Contacts

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

A user has asked a very interesting question.

Is there some way to filter out, but not delete, some of their personal contacts that are older? In essence if he has 100 contacts, he might want 20 to be active and the rest inactive.

He could of course make a group for this, but I don't think this would work using his email.

===================================

What he wants to be able to do is to "hide" his contacts when he is emailing (so type ahead). I have noticed that there is a feature in Recent Contacts for hide, which seems exactly what we need. We have turned off recent contacts by default (users can turn it on if they want) as it is so problematic. I wonder if we just tell this user to turn them on and hide ones they don't want to see?

Comment: What does the user mean by "filter out"? What does he think "active" versus "inactive" should mean? Does he not want to see them if they're inactive? Does he not want them to be used for auto-completion?

Comment: I have explained more in the original question.

Comment: This question really isn't right for StackOverflow since it's not a programming question. It's probably better for ServerFault - or maybe SuperUser. In any case, from a StackOverflow prespective - i.e., programming - I would think that you could provide users with a separate 'Archived Contacts' database and add an action button to the local names.nsf that moves selected contacts from there to the archive database.